# Difficult to handling json formatting in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I need convert json string from this array

```
( {
        1 = 4;
    },
        {
        8 = 20;
    })
```

Actually i need output like `{"custom":{"1":"3","8":"21"}}` but i got "`{\n  \"custom\" : \"[\\n  {\\n    \\\"1\\\" : \\\"4\\\"\\n  },\\n  {\\n    \\\"8\\\" : \\\"20\\\"\\n  }\\n]\"\n}"`

here is my code

```
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mydict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

is there any way to get output like this : `{"custom":{"1":"3","8":"21"}}`

Answer (score 3):

Just replace `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted` with 0.

Comment: Thank you now i got [{"1":"4"},{"8":"20"}] . can you help with how to make like this {"7":"8","8":"5"}

Comment: @Subramani - you have an array of dictionaries, if you want to output a single JSON dictionary the produce a single dictionary from your array before doing the JSON conversion.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted` option like this :

```
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mydict options:0 error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

According to the documentation `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted`adds whitespace to make the output readable , removing that option gives the most compact JSON possible .
More  [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsjsonwritingoptions?language=objc)

Comment: Thank you and i already done this is there any way to make like this  {"7":"8","8":"5"} from  [{"1":"4"},{"8":"20"}]